# get label (verbose_name) text from model to template django 3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have this model

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=multi_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    product_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to print this model **verbose_name** in the templates, example:

[image]

I want it to be printed dynamically not manually

**UPDATE 1**

This method

```
{{ myobject._meta.verbose_name }}
```

not working, I'm using django 3.0

I get this error

`Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'image.product_id._meta.verbose_name'`

Comment: What is `labels`? How does it relate to the model `Image`?

Comment: Hello, labels I mean _verbose_name_

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,

our app layout might look like this:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        poll_extras.py
    views.py
```

And in your template you would use the following:

```
{% load poll_extras %}
```

the app that contains the custom tags must be in **INSTALLED_APPS** in order for the *{% load %}* tag to work, like this :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls'
]
```

note that you should install your app like this **'polls'**, if you do **'polls.apps.Poll'** then the *{% load %}* will not work.

After that, in poll_extra.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def label_vb(instance, arg):
    return instance._meta.get_field(arg).verbose_name
```

then inside your template:

```
{{ image|label_vb:"porduct_id" }}
```